# Why does Django trigger GET after POST?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have the following view which takes either a URL or an uploaded text file,  creates a Word Cloud and finally displays the generated image to the user.

```
def create(request):
    """
    Displays the generated WordCloud from the
    given URI or uploaded file
    """
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    # in order to avoid KeyError
    myfile = request.FILES.get('myfile', None)

    if request.POST['uri'] == '' and myfile is None:
        return render(request, 'nube/index.html', {
            'error_message': NOTHING_TO_PROCESS
        })
    try:
        if myfile:
            cloud = WordCloud(myfile, type="upload")
        else:
            cloud = WordCloud(request.POST['uri'], type="internet")
    except (MissingSchema):
        return render(request, 'nube/index.html', {
            'error_message': URI_COULD_NOT_BE_PROCESSED
        })
    else:
        # img is a PIL.Image instance
        img = cloud.get_word_cloud_as_image()
        img.save(response, 'PNG')
        return response
```

The image is displayed with no problems; the POST request is processed properly, as can be seen from the log:

```
[16/Jan/2018 22:53:25] "POST /nube/create HTTP/1.1" 200 216961
```

However, even though the server didn't crash, I noticed an Exception was raised every time immediately after:

```
Internal Server Error: /nube/create                         
Traceback (most recent call last):                          
  File "C:\repos\phuyu\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 77, in __getitem__                  
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)                        
KeyError: 'uri'
```

After debugging the code I noticed that my `create` view was being called once again, but this time as a GET request, and of course, the parameters `uri` and `myfile` didn't exist this time, thus raising the exceptions.

To make sure, I changed `create` into a class based view and only defined its `post` method. As suspected, now I got the following line in the logs after the successful POST:

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /nube/create
[16/Jan/2018 22:44:41] "GET /nube/create HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

What would be the correct way to handle this? I'm fairly new to Django.

Comment: Post your `WordCloud` code.

Comment: If you are sending `uri` in post request then 
replace `request.POST['uri']`  with `request.POST.get['uri']` and this will resolve your error.

Comment: I tried your suggestions to no avail. The WordCloud code is huge and irrelevant since I have run many tests on it.

Comment: Are you sending `uri` in post request?

Comment: Can you post the class-based view code?

Comment: I don't think this would be a problem about server side, but maybe a problem about client side. Your client side wrongly send a duplicated `GET` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @usman-maqbool suggested, the problem was actually in my WordCloud clode, especifically, in `get_word_cloud_as_image()`, a trailing semicolon:

```
  def get_word_cloud_as_image(self):
        return self.img;
```

After removing it, there's no more sneaky GET requests. I'm not sure why it had that effect. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify.